# Is it a duplicate question if I need a more specific answer?

Tags: discussion

While looking for how to shoot a *nadir* image for a spherical panorama, I found [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/how-can-i-improve-stitching-of-nadir-and-zenith-shots-in-360-hemispheric-panos) relevant question which is a superset of what I am looking for.

Only thing is that answers are long-winded, convoluted and do not really address the question except for one which says in one part *use a fisheye lens* which I do not want (my question would require using a *rectilinear lens*) and in another part:

> There is of course a way to shoot nadir and zenith with a tripod to
>   eliminate it from the picture but believe me it is extremely
>   complicated and involves moving the whole tripod several times.

...which is too vague but what I am looking for. So, can this be cleaned up? If not, then I will need to ask another similarly sounding question. I guess my concern is that the question I wish to ask included in the one I found but the answer is not.

Comment: Your question might also be closed as "too localized", [such as this one requesting answers more specific to Europe](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/what-are-some-good-places-to-sell-photo-prints-online-with-a-focus-on-europe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go ahead and ask your question. It sounds like you need different and more precise answers than were provided by the one you linked, and I see no reason you should not be allowed to ask a question that you need a specific answer for. I'll throw on a comment once  you ask stating that while there is a similar question, your's is looking for a specific and detailed answer as indicated by your particular wording.

Comment: I agree, and will add that generally when asking a question you know is a more specific form of (or a followup to) an existing question, it's very useful to link to that question yourself.

Comment: (I prefer such links to be at the end of the question rather than as an intro, though, because people looking through search results excerpts should see the actual question, not preamble. Or even make it a comment to your own question.)

Comment: I totally agree with @mattdm's point about putting links at the end. Probably a good practice to use in general when asking similar-but-different questions.