# If the answers to a specific question also satisfies the answer to a generic form of the question what to do?

Tags: discussion

I guess this question is a reverse of:
[Is it a duplicate question if I need a more specific answer?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/is-it-a-duplicate-question-if-i-need-a-more-specific-answer)

If i ask a generic question and am pointed out to a specific question whose answer also satisfy my question is it worth updating the specific question to encompass the wording of the general one?

Specific example i asked about reporting on exif data: [Software to display statistics based on EXIF data?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/software-to-display-statistics-based-on-exif-data/21177) and was pointed out there is a similar question (albeit more specific) about focal lengths: [What software can show my most frequently used focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/what-software-can-show-my-most-frequently-used-focal-length) that has all the answer i need.

Logically this implies that my question should be closed but will this result in people perhaps in future then asking for what software to report on ISO speed etc? Thus should the generic wording be added to the more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Its worth having both around - simply because of the reason you pointed out.  More people will find the right answer.  They're not duplicate questions, but the answers are basically, at a generic level, duplicate.  And that's basically ok.

Comment: In this particular case, though, I think the answers to the specific question will always be _as general_ as those to the general question. Better to close (but not delete) future specific questions as duplicates of the general one.

Comment: Although also in this specific case, "focal length" is a _very_ common subset of the general.

Comment: @mattdm you're right about closing (not deleting) - for some reason I was just reading 'delete' instead of close

Comment: The distinction is kind of a Stack Exchange nuance. :)